# Web tools to show a comparison between two values?

Tags: gui-design

I would like to compare two values and show a comparison (or a variation) between the two values. Here is an example in my desktop app:

[image]

This app is developed in Delphi so I don't have a lot of choices for the UI, but with the web version I think there are better tools to achieve this. Do you know some tools that are user-friendly and prettier than the screenshot above?

Thanks

Comment: questions about implementation and/or software/tool recommendations are considered 'Off Topic' here. Can you change your question so that it is about solving a UX issue and not a request for opinions about tools?

Comment: I'm not asking for opinions about tools, I'm asking if tools that can achieve my goal exist or if I have to do it by myself.

Comment: That would be implementation then - I don't think you'l get any answers and the question is likely to be closed at some point.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few "frameworks" you can use for easier layout and even dynamic data representation.

Most popular of these is probably Angular, from google.

https://angularjs.org

Second most popular is (probably) React from Facebook.

They might do what you want.